# Understand cross entropy's calculation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, self-learning

Screenshot from [this video.](https://youtu.be/ErfnhcEV1O8?t=470)

Why he calculate predicted probability by using $\frac{1}{\text{bit length}^2}$, what does those calculated probability means? I added up all the predicted distribution and it is $93.x\%$ not $100\%$ but true distribution is $100\%$ why not match? what is the difference means? Is this difference KL-divergence?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability values being used are coming from Claude Shannon's paper *A Mathematical Theory of Communication* mentioned at the beginning of the video, and are putting the data in terms of binary bits *n*, i.e.:

$\frac{1}{2^n}$

where they're base 2 because the data is being sent as binary data.  He mentions in the video that the code doesn't use messages starting with `1111` so if you add up the values they don't sum to 100%.

If the cross entropy is greater than the entropy, this is what's called the KL or Kullback–Leibler divergence.

Comment: I the video, seems he calculate cross-entropy with real distribution and length of binary string not that $\frac{1}{2^n}$, so what does that percentage of binary means? That is the part i can't understand.